# EMF being equal through KVL

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, batteries

[image]

In the given figure,we connect three cells of *different* emf which are $V_1,V_2,V_3$ with a resistance $R$ in the first loop. Now suppose we emit current $I$ from $V_1$. $I$ gets divided into $I_1$ and $I_2$ with $I_1$ flowing through $V_2$ and $I_2$ through $V_3$.

Now if i apply KVL in the second loop where their are only voltage sources $V_2$ and $V_3$, we will get $-V_3+V_2=0$ or $V_2=V_3$ but that's a contradiction since we took the $3$ cells of different emfs. Where am i making a mistake? Is KVL not applicable to this loop? Or did i make a mistake in dividing the currents? Kindly correct me.

**ADDENUM:**
As per the answers,i came to the conclusion that it is impossible to make such a circuit. But the following is an old problem from an olympiad.(A previous post of mine was closed alleging it to be a homework problem even though i was making sure if the problem was wrong or not)

[image]

All the diodes are ideal here so that should mean there is no potential drop and they are just behaving as a normal wire which is the situation i have in the original question,then how is the circuit they made even possible to exist? As per the above answers,if my given circuit cant exist,then so can't the circuit in this problem.

Comment: No source is ideal in real life. They all have output (series) resistance so there are no contradictions in real life. Ideal things simplify analysis but can't truly exist because *somewhere* there is a scenario where a contradiction that will arise if they did. What you're doing exactly like a student setting up a problem with an unstoppable force meeting an immovable object and then asking what went wrong. You need to know the limits of your model.

Comment: A diode with Vf=0V ist just a normal wire because it only conducts one way. That diode circuit is fine because only one diode will conduct (the one with lowest voltage source producing the greatest voltage difference across the diode, and when it does the other diodes become reverse biased.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit elaborately? Sorry for asking too much but i am still a beginner.

Comment: what is the emf for the first diode. You blocked it with the cursor.

Comment: That's 1 volt..

Comment: @madness You say an ideal diode has voltage drop of 0V which means it is like a wire. This is wrong because it can still prevent current going backwards through it. An ideal wire has a voltage drop of 0V in both directions. An ideal diode has a voltage drop of 0V in the forward direction and up to infinite in the reverse direction (ie as much as necessary to prevent reverse current flow).

Comment: But as the first diode is forward biased,how can it prevent current?Aren't all diodes forward biased here? Since current will be emitten from the 10 volt source only?

Comment: When the first diode conducts the voltage on both ends of the diode becomes the same because 0V drop. This makes all the other diodes reverse biased because their top terminal all share that 1V when the leftmost diode conducts.

Comment: Extremely sorry for bothering,but i still didn't understand why the other diodes will become reverse biased. No currents are being emitted from any voltage source apart from the 10 volt,and the direction of current is the same as that of the diode,so shouldn't current from 10 volt pass through all diodes?

Comment: When leftmost diode conducts the other diodes get 1V on the anode and 4V or 9V on the cathode =  Reverse biased.

Comment: Oh i get it now,thanks a lot!

Comment: @madness Do you understand why we assume only the first (left most) diode conducts given that the 10 V supply voltage exceeds the cathode voltages of all three diodes?

Comment: Isn't it because current from 10 volt source will enter that diode first?And when current sees that the upcoming diodes apart from the left most ones are reverse biased,then current will not divide further and the whole current will flow through the first diode. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You can actually choose any diode as the first to turn on but if you work out the voltages there you find conditions that will cause another diode with lower voltage to turn on instead. If you work it all out repeatedly you find only one stable condition. We know this so we just shortcut to the lowest voltage diode since it is the only stable configuration. Has nothing to do with being closest to the 10V source since that is completely arbitrary and is only about how you chose to arrange thins when you drew the schematic.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation. A really dumb question from a noob if you do not mind,how do we work out the voltages to find that the lower rank voltage will be turned on? Also could you please tell which conditions you mentioned?

Comment: Start by guessing which diode turns on. Then set the anode voltages appropriately (in this case anode becomes same as cathode voltage because ideal diode so 0V drop). See if this still allows other diodes to be forward biased instead. Repeat by guessing which of the remaining diodes that are now forward biased will conduct. Keep repeating until there's nowhere left to go.

Answer (score 4):

The mistake you are making is trying to connect two ideal batteries $V_2$ and $V_3$ with different EMFs in parallel, winding up with the inconsistency of having two different voltages in parallel,  whereas the voltage across any two parallel components has to be the same.

When connecting batteries in parallel, you need to include the internal resistance that exists in all real batteries.

Your ADDENDUM:

There is no inconsistency here because only the diode with the 1 volt emf battery will be forward biased and conduct. Then the voltage across that diode/emf combination will be 1 volt with a voltage drop across the 1 K resistor being 9 volts. The one volt drop will keep the other two diodes reverse biased.

One might  ask, "why is it assumed only the first diode conducts given the fact that the voltage of the supply battery exceeds all of the cathode voltages?".  The answer would be, assuming all the wires connecting the anodes have zero resistance, there can only be one voltage common to all the anodes.

Let's assume that the second diode (from the left) conducts instead of the first. That would make the anode potential for all three diodes 4V. The third diode will still be reverse biased and therefore not conduct. But the first diode will be forward biased and conduct. If that actually happened, then we would simultaneously have two different potentials, 1V and 4V, for the same electrical point in the circuit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This entire issue can be avoided given that we do not use the idealisation that the potential difference across an ideal wire is zero. This idealisation is not true. The presence of some "internal resistance" can  be used to fix this, but a better way is to just accept there IS potential difference across an ideal wire.

Analysing the second loop, can be done by imagining there are 2 different loops, one with one battery and one with another.

Potential is a scalar and so can then be added up to find the PD across a closed loop.

The first loop starting anticlockwise from the positive terminal is

$$- V_{2} + V_{2} =  0$$

The second

$$ -V_{3} + V_{3} =  0$$

The total PD from both batteries is

$$- V_{2} + V_{2} + -V_{3} + V_{3} = 0$$

There is no error that the potentials are the same, the only reason you got that result is by ignoring the PD across the wires.

More directly, this can also fix the apparent contradiction that the potential from each branch is the same, despite having batteries of different potentials. Potential decreases along the wire to make up for this difference, it is not just the batteries EMF inside the battery you need to worry about.